# How print json post body with RestTemplate

Tags: java, jackson, resttemplate, spring-web

I need to know, if jackson is doing the correct parse on my class attributes annotated with @JsonProperty, but enabling debug spring options, it does not display the json that was generated in the post. 
I tried to create some interceptors to do this task but it did not work, does anyone know if there is any jackson setup that print the payload in the post operation?

Answer (score 1):

just write a unit test for your pojo like this:

```
@Test
public void testSerialization() throws Exception {
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(yourObjectToBeSerialized);

 //  and simple print it

    System.out.println(json);

//   or do some assertions
```